# Multiple entries in an LL(1) parsing table?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, context-free-grammar, ll-grammar

Given this grammar:

> S → S<sub>1</sub> S<sub>2</sub>
>
> S<sub>1</sub> → a | ε
>
> S<sub>2</sub> → ab | ε

Therefore, we have

> FIRST(S<sub>1</sub>) = { a, ε }
>
> FOLLOW(S<sub>1</sub>) = { a }

Does that mean that in the parsing table I'll have multiple definitions in the row for S<sub>1</sub> and the column for `a`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct.  (However, note that your FOLLOW set is wrong; it also contains the end-of-input marker $).  The issue here is that if the parser sees an `a`, it can't tell if that's because it wants to use the derivation

> S → S<sub>1</sub>S<sub>2</sub> → a S<sub>2</sub>

Or the derivation

> S → S<sub>1</sub>S<sub>2</sub> → S<sub>2</sub> → ab

To fix this, you can note that your grammar only generates the strings { a, ab, aab }.  Therefore, you can build an LL(1) for the language grammar that directly produces those three strings:

> S → aY
>
> Y → ε | aZ
>
> Z → ε | b

Hope this helps!

Comment: But why $ is in the follow of S1 ??
Because S2 contains epsilon ?

Comment: @MarounSassine- Yes, that's correct.  Because S2 has epsilon in its FIRST set, the FOLLOW set for S1 contains everything in the FOLLOW set for S2.  Since S2 comes at the very end of the start production, its follow set contains $.  Therefore, S1's FOLLOW set contains $.  Does that explain things?

Comment: @templatetypedef sorry to barge in here, actually I am interested in compiler design and found your slides https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs143/cs143.1128/ I found them very intuitive but sometimes I find them shallow where you repeat slides I think you must be explaining in class or something, how could I get more resources / help from your notes?